# Having an issue with horizontal scrolling in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

When I try to scroll horizontally in Google Spreadsheets using the track pad, nothing happens. However, if I scroll vertically first, I can then scroll horizontally if I don't pick up my fingers from the track pad. This seems like a simple event handler bug on their part. Is anyone else having this issue or know a fix?

If it's relevant (probably isn't), I'm using Firefox 26.0 on a MacBook running OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with Safari or Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a known Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=948510 (Alas, it was opened more than year ago…)

Answer (score 1):

On the spreadsheet menu. There is help->Report issue.

It sounds like the track pad is doing something strange, because all works when I use a mouse.

Answer (score -1):

the trick is to freeze pane row 1, then you can scroll as much as you like on a google sheet :)